# List Comprehension Ignores the Third Element

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following list comprehension:

```
cd.impending_events = [cd.priority_queue.pop(i) for i, x in enumerate(cd.priority_queue) if round(x[0], cd.precision) == round(cd.simulation_time, cd.precision)]
```

It's pulling values out based on the current time.
I believe I should never see old time values in my priority queue.

Here is a snippet from my log file:

```
2.69
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 1]
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.7, 0, 'vwall', 5]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 0]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 2]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]

2.7
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 0]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 2]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 6]
[4.36, 0, 'vwall', 6]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]

2.71
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 0]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 2]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 6]
[4.36, 0, 'vwall', 6]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]
```

The current time is printed and then the priority queue at the current time is printed in the log file.
At time 2.7, one of the elements was left behind.

The same thing happens at 2.73:

```
2.72
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 0]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 2]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 6]
[4.36, 0, 'vwall', 6]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]

2.73
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 6]
[4.36, 0, 'vwall', 6]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]

2.74
[2.7, 1, 'hwall', 2]
[2.73, 0, 'vwall', 1]
[2.78, 1, 'vwall', 5]
[3.27, 0, 'vwall', 4]
[3.5, 1, 'hwall', 4]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 5]
[3.56, 0, 'hwall', 6]
[4.36, 0, 'vwall', 6]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 3]
[5.75, 1, 'vwall', 4]
[12.1, 1, 'hwall', 5]
```

I think it only happens when there are 3 elements available. I see nothing special about these particular elements.

Why is my list comprehension skipping the third element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/4788546

Comment: ^^ The index you get from `enumerate` is not anymore the correct index after you have already popped a few elements.

Comment: @trincot does it enumerate the list with each check of the element?

Comment: "Why is my list comprehension skipping the third element?" because the third element ceases to be the third element after you mutate the list.